# New bike chain?

Tags: chain

I know very little about bikes but have just changed my gearing to 40 single on the front and a 11-28 on the back of my Mountain Bike . 
What would be the right chain length to get please ?

Comment: Park tools has a step-by-step of Sheldon Brown's rule-of-thumb: https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/chain-length-sizing#article-section-4

Comment: Chains come in one length and are cut down to fit specific bikes. Chainstay length as well as chainring and sprocket size determine the correct chain length.

Comment: OOH thanks I'll have to study that